# Making a program where LEDS are individually turned on and off according to the sequence

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am writing a program where I have to turn the LEDS on and off according to the following sequence, (delay of half a second between each state):

State 1- Led 1 ON Led 2 ON Led 3 OFF

State 2- Led 1 OFF Led 2 ON Led 3 ON

State 3- Led 1 ON Led 2 OFF Led 3 OFN

The LEDs are located on the OLED1 Xplained extension of the ATmega324PB Microcontroller, and I am using the IAR Embedded Workbench. This is the code I've written so far:

```
#include "iom324pb.h"
#include <ioavr.h>

#include <intrinsics.h>

void led3_on()
{  
  DDRA_DDRA3=1;
  PINA_PINA3=1;
}

void led3_off()
{
   DDRA_DDRA3=0;
}

void led2_on()
{
  DDRD_DDRD4=1;
  PIND_PIND4=1;

}

void led2_off()
{
  DDRD_DDRD4=0;
}

void led1_on()
{
   DDRD_DDRD5=1;
   PIND_PIND5=1;
}

void led1_off()
{
  DDRD_DDRD5=0;
}

void state1()
{
     led3_off();
     led2_on();
     led1_on();
}

void state2()
{
   led3_on();
   led1_off();
}

void state3()
{
  led2_off();
}

void main (void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    state1();
    __delay_cycles(8000000);
    state2();
    __delay_cycles(8000000);
    state3();
     __delay_cycles(8000000);
  }

}
```

I have managed to do the first 2 states but I have trouble with the last one. Basically for some reason I don't understand if I try to turn LED1 back on it would mess up the whole sequence.

Comment: What would "mess up the whole sequence" mean? Your code does not even try to turn LED1 on again in `state3`. What is the result if you try it?

Comment: I never used this board so I honestly have no idea but: why do you use the _direction_ bit (instead of the data bit) to turn leds on/off?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and *copy&paste* your code. Please clarify the meaning of the registers like `DDRA_DDRA3` (direction?) and `PINA_PINA3` (data?). I would expect that you switch the GPIO direction to output once and set the output to high or low to switch the LEDs. There is a typo in State 3: OFN. I would expect that in the `stateX` functions the ecpected state of all 3 LEDs should be set to make the functions independent from the actual call sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`state3()` is missing a `led1_on();`

There is little reason to only adjust 2 LEDs per state.  **Turn off/on all 3** in each `stateN()`.

There is also little reason to only adjust 1 register when turning the LED on/off.  **Set both the pin and the DDR** in each `ledN_...()`. funciton.